What is this value that pandas is returning from a url?
I'm trying to read a table from an URL with pandas but it's returning some weird value for the characters column:
# 3rd party apps use "pip install pandas lxml"
import pandas as pd

url = "https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vRMx5YQlZNa3ra8dYYxmv-QIQ3YJe8tbI3kqcuC7lQiZm-CSEznKfN_HYNSpoXcZIV3Y_O3YoUB1ecq/pub"
c = pd.read_html(url)
print(c)

Output:
[              0          1             2
 0  x-coordinate  Character  y-coordinate
 1             0        â             0
 2             0        â             1
 3             0        â             2
 4             1        â             1
 5             1        â             2
 6             2        â             1
 7             2        â             2
 8             3        â             2]

When I print the specific characters I get this:
>>> c[0][1][1]
'â\x96\x88'

At first I assumed this was the hex number of the character but when I checked it I found that it wasn't. I'm not too sure what the significance of the â character is.

It's the utf-8 encoding for a block character at code point U+2588. It's the same as '\xe2\x96\x88'. See here: https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=9600&number=128&names=-&utf8=string-literal Try reading the html with c = pd.read_html(url, encoding='utf-8')

To understand encodings: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html and https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Another, although very technical, reference relevant for web is the HTML Encoding spec. Especially the table indicating which encoding labels use which encoder/decoder pair.

read_html() uses the parsing engine in use to determine the encoding. In this case the HTML being retrieved has a few internationalisation errors , including not identifying the encoding within the document.  The parser is incorrectly identifying the encoding, which may be a result of the other errors in the HTML document. The encoding parameter in read_html() allows you to override it.

you can specify the encoding parameter in read_html() to handle the special character.
You can try:
url = "https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vRMx5YQlZNa3ra8dYYxmv-QIQ3YJe8tbI3kqcuC7lQiZm-CSEznKfN_HYNSpoXcZIV3Y_O3YoUB1ecq/pub"
c = pd.read_html(url, encoding='latin1')


Or
url = "https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vRMx5YQlZNa3ra8dYYxmv-QIQ3YJe8tbI3kqcuC7lQiZm-CSEznKfN_HYNSpoXcZIV3Y_O3YoUB1ecq/pub"
c = pd.read_html(url, encoding='utf-8')


It would be better to use windows-1252 rather than latin1 or iso-8859-1, since the encoding labels mean different things in Python versus the HTML encoding spec.
